# Docker Joomla + MySQL how to make joomla website persistent

Tags: mysql, docker, joomla, persistent

I am busy with creating mysql + joomla in docker. But everytime I delete the old container and create a new Joomla container with the same parameters, I have to do the installation of joomla again. How can I make the Joomla website persistent so that everytime I create a new joomla container I don't have to redo the installation in the webbrowser.

I tried creating an image of the already installed Joomla container but that didn't give me any success.

Also I mounted the `/var/www/html` folder of the joomla container, but still the same problem.

This is the commands I use to create both containers:

mysql:

```
docker run \
  --name JoomlaDB \
  -d \
  -p 3306:3306 \
  -e MYSQL_USER=JoomlaUser \
  -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=password \
  -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password \
  -e MYSQL_DATABASE=joomla \
  -v db_volume:/var/lib/mysql \
  mysql:5.7
```

Joomla:

```
docker run \
  -d \
  -p 8080:80 \
  -e JOOMLA_DB_HOST=JoomlaDB:3306 \
  -e JOOMLA_DB_USER=JoomlaUser \
  -e JOOMLA_DB_PASSWORD=password \
  -e JOOMLA_DB_NAME=joomla \
  --link JoomlaDB:mysql \
  -v joomla_volume:/var/www/html \
  joomla
```

Thanks in advance for the answers!

Comment: Typically you'd create a Docker image containing your code; you shouldn't need a volume or to manually install things once the application is running.  The official Docker [Sample application](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/02_our_app/) tutorial walks through this process (for a Node application, but it's the same for most languages).

Comment: How do you delete the old container ? Which command ? Your commands look ok so far. I would suggest using `docker-compose` instead as shown the [container documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/joomla)

Comment: When I try to replicate your issue, it works as it should. The configuration is stored in /var/www/html/configuration.php, so it is stored in your `joomla_volume` volume and persisted when the container exits.

Comment: The best place to ask question that pertain to Joomla and its extension is on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.  On the off chance that a non-Joomla contributor can answer a Joomla question, it is likely that they will be unaware of caveats, vulnerabilities or special features which are available.

Comment: @HansKilian If you are able to offer insights/support for Joomla questions, please join us at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Have a lock on DPDocker where I do the same with docker-compose https://github.com/Digital-Peak/DPDocker/blob/main/webserver/docker-compose.yml